# Add link to ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I have a `ModelForm`:

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ApiBackendConfigForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs['instance'].name == u'Some_name':
            self.fields['method_config'] = forms.URLField()
```

and `ModelAdmin`:

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SomeModelForm
    list_display = ('name', 'alias', 'is_enabled', )
    list_editable = ('is_enabled', )
    readonly_fields = ('name', 'alias', )
```

First question, `method_config` field is not displayed. I know, that it's not in `list_display`, but if I add it to `list_display`, then it causes an error.

**And second main question: How can I add some link to other `ModelAdmin`?**

Comment: I don't think you're showing enough information. What do you expect `method_config` to display when you add it to `list_display`. Where do you want to display the link, and what exactly do you want to link to?

Comment: @Alasdair, `method_config` should display a link to new ModelAdmin that is not written yet.

Comment: depending on object.name

Comment: Do you want there to be a form field when editing an item, or just a link when displaying the overview? I still don't understand what url you want to link to.

Answer (score 0):

Modifing `self.fields` might not be thread-safe. This means that if you modify self.fields on first request, all other requests will get that modified version.

Check [ModelAdmin.get_fields(request, obj=None)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) method for changing which  fields to display on the fly. Works on forms in changeview. If you want to display custom field in changelist view, just modify list_display wih method name instead of field.

For example:

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'alias', 'is_enabled', 'show_method_config', )
    list_editable = ('is_enabled', )
    readonly_fields = ('name', 'alias', )

    def show_method_config(self,obj):
        return getattr(obj,"method_config","") if obj.name == u"Some_name" else ""
    show_method_config.short_description = _(u"Method config")
    show_method_config.admin_order_field = "method_config"
    show_method_config.allow_tags = True

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super(SomeAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        if obj and obj.name == u"Some_name":
            fields.append("method_config")
        return fields
```

Comment: `method_config` is not a model field

Comment: it's not displaying anything

Comment: If you want to produce url address to certain model view, try `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`  `reverse("admin:{{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_add")` Check [Django admin site docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) for all available routes.